# How to setup Tomcat for multiple Spring application profiles

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-profiles

How to set Spring application to use multiple application profiles for different webapps?

Actually we are using setenv.sh batch with:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=test"
```

But on same server there will be production app too, with different profile.

We are not using web.xml in our app.

Comment: if the both profiles may be at the same server, the best option would be to set the profiles during app build

Comment: Thanks, we finally went this way

Answer (score 2):

Each applications can define a properties files where you can define the property `spring.profiles.active`